# Separate filename and path inside find command's -exec option

Tags: bash, find

I'm struggling with escaping and expression evaluation.  I am trying to run a command inside a `find`...`-exec COMMAND` structure, where `COMMAND` operates on one file and outputs to the stdout.  To use this `COMMAND` normally on the command line, I simply redirect to a new file, like this:

```
COMMAND inputfilename.md > outputfilename.md.conf
```

This works fine.  However, if I want to recursively loop over *ALL* the files in a directory and its subdirectory, using `find -exec`, I can't seem to figure out how to separate the file name and the path so that I can redirect properly.  For example, this produces an error:

```
find ./ *.md -not -path './/.git/*' -exec COMMAND '{} > ~/wiki/newdirectory/{}.cong' \;
```

because `{}` expands the entire file path.  I've tried various combinations of `basename` and `dirname`, but I can't seem to get them to evaluate (instead, I just get the string 'basename' etc.). For example, this didn't work, because the text 'basename' just shows up

```
find ./ *.md -not -path './/.git/*' -exec COMMAND  '{} > ~/wiki/newdirectory/''basename {}''.conf' \;
```

(returns this error: `'No such file or directory - .//newdirectory/README.md.conf > ~/wiki/newdirectory/basename .//newdirectory/README.md.conf'`).

Any help would be appreciated.  To summarize, the objective is:

1. Recursively iterate over all files matching `*.md` in a directory
2. Execute `COMMAND inputfile.md > ~/newdirectory/inputfile.md.conf` where `inputfile` is the same string in each iteration.

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `-not -path`, you should use `-prune`.

Comment: Also, does it have to be directly `-exec`? Can you use `xargs` or `bash -c '...'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever you do, you'll need to invoke a shell to perform the redirection of the command output to a file whose location depends on the `find` result.

```
find ./ *.md -not -path './/.git/*' -exec sh -c 'COMMAND "$0" > ~/wiki/newdirectory/"${0##*/}.cong"' {} \;
```

Don't substitute `{}` inside the shell script. This isn't supported on all systems, and even where it is, that would not work in general, since it would treat the file name as a piece of shell syntax, e.g. a file called `;rm -rf ~;.md` would cause you to erase all your files.

`${0##*/}` uses pure string manipulation to obtain the base name of the file. You could also use `$(basename -- "$0")`.

Answer (score 1):

If your `find` accepts `-execdir`, this should work

```
find . -name '*.md' -not -path './/.git/*' -execdir COMMAND {} > ~/wiki/newdirectory/{}.cong \;
```

Alternately

```
find . -name '*.md' -not -path './/.git/*' -exec bash -c \
'for f; do COMMAND "$f" > ~/wiki/newdirectory/"${f##*/}".cong; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `find` is not actually executing inside each file's respective directory with `-execdir`.  This appears possibly to be a [known bug in OS X `find`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074060/execdir-interpretation-on-linux-and-osx).  I'm poking at it now.

Comment: @jbeldock, added an alternative

Comment: The first command can't work this way: you need to invoke a shell to perform the redirection. What you wrote redirects the output of the `find` command and all the subprocesses it launches to a file named `~/wiki/newdirectory/{}.cong` (with the braces in the file name). @jbeldock

Comment: Thanks, I see the need for `exec` now.  Just have to wrap my head around the string manipulations.  :-)